# Not referring the specific class c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, api

I'm developing a small weather app which uses openweathermap api which works almost fine. But this code block which is going to save a city name to a text file doesn't work. Can anyone help.

This is the calling function which is in the MainWindow.Xaml.cs

```
private void setCurrentCityButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CurrentCity.UpdateCurrentCity();
}
```

This is the called function which is in CurrentCity.cs

```
AllWeather _allWeather = new AllWeather();
//Update Current City to a text file using SteamWriter
static public void UpdateCurrentCity()
{         
    using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("currentCity.txt"))
    {
        str.WriteLine("Test");//This works fine so no issue with rest
        str.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(_allWeather.name));//code runs but doesn't get the required name from the AllWeather Class
    }
}
```

The AllWeather class:

```
public class AllWeather 
{ 
    public Coord coord { get; set; } 
    public Weather[] weather { get; set; } 
    public string _base { get; set; } 
    public Main main { get; set; } 
    public int visibility { get; set; } 
    public Wind wind { get; set; } 
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; } 
    public int dt { get; set; } 
    public Sys sys { get; set; } 
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public int cod { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: *doesn't work* doesn't really describe the error, the code/message would also help. Regardless, is the line `AllWeather _allWeather = new AllWeather();` exactly there? Meaning, is it in the constructor of the `CurrentCity` class? For more information you could show part/all of the implementation of `AllWeather` class.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, sorry my bad  AllWeather class is a json converted class and is contaning weather details. I'm trying to get the city's name from it which is working in other parts of the program. The code below doesn't show an error but not writing the name of the city to the text file mentioned above

    str.WriteLine(_allWeather.name);

Still it's working and replacing any typed text with whitespace, The city name is not fetched from the AllWeather class. Even tried placing
AllWeather _allWeather = new AllWeather(); inside the method same result

Comment: Could you use debugging mode and add a breakpoint after the line `str.WriteLine("Test");` and check the `_allWeather` variable to make sure it has a name? Alternative would be `Console.WriteLine(_allWeather.name);`.

Comment: the _allWeather.name is null it shows

Comment: So this becomes another problem, not one related to writing to text files at all. Depending on whether `_allWeather` itself is null (means it was not initialized properly / at all) or `_allWeather.name` specifically is null (means there is something wrong with your JSON conversion).

Comment: hardly figured it out.. ya the name variable doesn't is empty. There must be an initializing problem, since the other parts in the mainwindow class identifies name. Any way to figure this out

Comment: You'll need to show some code related to this line `AllWeather _allWeather = new AllWeather();`. Is the JSON same as that in mainwindow class?

Comment: See this class
 
public class AllWeather
    {
        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        public Weather[] weather { get; set; }
        public string _base { get; set; }
        public Main main { get; set; }
        public int visibility { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public int dt { get; set; }
        public Sys sys { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int cod { get; set; }
    }

Comment: The code for the class does not help much, please kindly show the JSON deserialization code, optionally also the one used in the other place (which apparently works).

Comment: @KeyurPATEL
 //Converting the JSON response to classes in the AllWeather Class
            _allWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllWeather>(response);

            //Temperature
            temperatureLabel.Content = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(_allWeather.main.temp)) + "° C";
            //cityNameLabel.Content = _allWeather.name + ", " + _allWeather.sys.country;
            cityNameLabel.Content = _allWeather.name;

Comment: I realize I keep asking for more, but the code you've provided **still** does not help me figure out whats wrong. Could you show some/all of the json? Also, as an example, you can try to see if other properties such as `_base` or `id` are getting set correctly.

Comment: the thing is the UpdateCurrentCity() method was in the main class which worked perfectly earlier then I moved it to a different class to reduce code lines in the main class. As I said you there's no error in receiving the JSON. theres a problem with referencing the AllWeather I think class. Btw, is there a way to fetch the _allWeather which is in the mainclass showed in the previous comment. At least it might help this. Thanks for being helpful

Comment: One of the simpler ways would be to have a parameter, e.g. `static public void UpdateCurrentCity(AllWeather _allWeather)` and just use that. Then, from your other class, you can just deserialize the response first, then call `CurrentCity.UpdateCurrentCity(_allWeather);`.

Comment: ok I'll try this . put it as an answer cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is actually with the `AllWeather` class and its construction, you can simply create it in your main class and add it as a parameter for the function:

```
private void setCurrentCityButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //something like var _allWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllWeather>(response);
    CurrentCity.UpdateCurrentCity(_allWeather);
}
```

And in your other class:

```
static public void UpdateCurrentCity(AllWeather _allWeather)
{         
    using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("currentCity.txt"))
    {
        str.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(_allWeather.name));
    }
}
```